# UnitOfWork Implementation

Tags: nhibernate, design-patterns, transactions, unit-of-work

probably I'm too n00b to understand this, but I was reading the Gabriel Schenker http://nhibernate.info/doc/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.html UnitOfWork implementation and I really cannot get the point.

Why does the UnitOfWorkImplementor.Dispose need to forward the dispose to the UnitOfWorkFactory and this forwards to UnitOfWork??? Why on earth cannot UnitOfWorkImplementor Dispose itself?

Is there any other UnitOfWork implementation example around? (An easier one please).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the static UnitOfWork needs to be told the current UoW is no longer available.